# how to know : it's phone or tablet?

Tags: android, tablet

I created app which work very good on tablet and phones. For detect (Settings for interface) im used width and heigh.. `if width > 1280` - it's must be tablet.. But.. my friend tested this app on samsung galaxy note.. This is a small phone (NOT TABLET)BUT screeen resolution there = 1280x800. And now i have problem with displaying there.. Can any tell me - is there a way to detect: tablet or phone  ??

Please tell me if anyone know..

Regards Peter.

p.s sorry for my bad english.. i trying be better.

Comment: I don't think so its possible... because android OS developer believes that your application willadapt itself no matter which is the device.. May be thats why they have different drawable folder for low , medium and high resolution...

Comment: @Kheldar http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_Screenshot.png/800px-Samsung_Galaxy_Note_Screenshot.png  see this image..  mb im not right understand u

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, found in Chrome to Phone extension example:

```
static boolean isTablet (Context context) {
        // TODO: This hacky stuff goes away when we allow users to target devices
        int xlargeBit = 4; // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;  // upgrade to HC SDK to get this
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        return (config.screenLayout & xlargeBit) == xlargeBit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Width (or height) in pixel determine not the screen size. The screen size depends on the resolution (pixels) and the density. Android provides various concepts to support different screen sizes. See here for details: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Very good link. I would add that specifically, you may find layout-large, layout-normal, etc, of most use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Device Atlas](http://deviceatlas.com/) to detect these features off the User Agent. The offer an API that you can host yourself, and they also offer a cloud service. Both are premium (paid-for)

Alternatively you can use something like [Wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) which, in my experience, is less accurate.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for designing for multiple screen see if it helps.
[Multiple screen designing](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

For a phone to be a phone, it must be able to make calls. Why don't you check the TelephonyManager There is a method called getPhoneType(). If it returns PHONE_TYPE_NONE, then it is not a phone.